# Spring JDBC and SQLUpdate for Where IN Clause

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-jdbc

I was working on an enhancement where I needed to make some changes in the spring config file to write SQL queries to delete some rows based on a Where IN clause;
I am not able to use the `java.sql.Types.ARRAY` it gives me :

> SQL state [99999]; error code [17059]; Fail to convert to internal
>   representation: [HOMEPHONE, WORKPHONE];

I added My code in the existing config file:

spring config file :
 `

```
<!--SQL static types -->
<bean id="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR"       class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean" />

<!--SQL query-->
    <property name="deletePhoneByPhoneType">
        <bean class="com.cigna.myapp.dao.UpdateWithParameters" parent="dao.template">
            <constructor-arg ref="myapp.ds" />
            <constructor-arg>
                <value>
                        <![CDATA[
            DELETE FROM PHONE            
             WHERE ID = ? AND
                   PH_TY NOT IN (?)
                     ]]>
                </value>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <list>
                    <ref local="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" />
                    <ref local="java.sql.Types.ARRAY" />
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>

public UpdateWithParameters(final DataSource ds, final String queryString, final List<?> types)
{
    super(ds, queryString);

    if ((types != null) && !types.isEmpty())
    {
        for (Iterator<?> itr = types.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
        {
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter(((Integer) itr.next()).intValue()));
        }
    } else
    {
        throw new DataRetrievalFailureException("UpdateWithParameters::Constructor: Missing parameter types.");
    }

    compile();
}`
```

I am sending ArrayList for the IN clause parameter.

Any help is appreciated     as how to map the `phTypeList` I am sending from my `DAOImpl` class.